# Node.js chat app append styled text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, node.js

I made a chat app with node.js where the client enters in a username and then can send messages. It appends the message in a `<ul>` for the other users to see: "username: message". I wanted to make the username bold and blue. How can it be done with the least amount of code?

HTML (without style)

```
<!doctype html>


<html>


  <head>

    <title>Lucas Chat</title>


  </head>



  <body>
      <div id="top">
          <h1>Welcome to the chat!</h1>
          <br>
          <p>Enter in a nickname and a message to get started</p>
          <br>
          <p id="drop">Scroll up or down to view newer/older messages</p>

      </div>

    <ul id="messages">







      </ul>


    <form action="">

      <input id="u" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Nickname"/><input id="m" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Message"/><button>Send</button>
    </form>



      <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      var socket = io();
  $('form').submit(function(){

      if ($('#m').val() != '' && $('#u').val() != '') {

    socket.emit('send message', {msg:$('#m').val(),user:$('#u').val()});
    $('#u').css("display", "none")
    $('#m').css("width", "90%")
    $("#u").css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)")
    $("#m").css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)")
    $('#m').val('');

      } else if ($('#u').val() === '' && $('#m').val() === '') {
         $("#u").css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 15px #ff8989")
         $("#m").css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 15px #ff8989")
      } else if ($('#u').val() === '' && $('#m').val() != '') {
          $("#u").css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 15px #ff8989")
          $("#m").css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)")
      } else if ($('#m').val() === '' && $('#u').val() != '') {
          $("#m").css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 15px #ff8989")
          $("#u").css("box-shadow", "0px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)")
      }

    return false;
  });
  socket.on('receive message', function(msg){
    $('#messages').append($('<li>').html(msg));
  });
    </script>



  </body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var peopleCount = 0;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){

peopleCount++

  console.log('a user connected | connections: ' + peopleCount)

  socket.on('disconnect', function(){

peopleCount--

  console.log('a user disconnected | connections: ' + peopleCount)

  });
});


io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('send message', function(data){
    io.emit('receive message', data.user + ': ' + data.msg);
  });
});

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var username = "<span style='font-weight:bold;color:blue;'>"+$('#u').val()+"</span>";

socket.emit('send message', {msg:$('#m').val(),user:username});
```